# Send a Javascript Array to a Controller And Render View Result in Another URL

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying with no success for 4 days now, I'm a Junior Dev, so that's why.

**Context:**

I have a [flexigrid](http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/) where I show the data collected from database, in a very particular column, there's a checkbox, I create a javascript function that gets the entity **Id** when you click on the checkbox and stores it on an **javascript** **array**, that I want to send to an **ActionResult**.

**Problem:**

I can pass using Ajax, but I can't render the ActionResult view, I get 404. Trying to use a `@Html.ActionLink`but doens't reconize the javascript array.
So how it's the way I can post the javascript array to a controller and follow that controller flow, like render another view with another URL ?

**Javascript Array:**

```js
var arrayId = new Array();
```

**View:**

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { area = "SomeArea", arrayId = arrayId })">
```

**Controller:**

> ```
> public ActionResult SomeAction(object[] arrayId)
> {
>   //some code
>
>   return View("AnotherView");
> }
> ```

**Ways to solution:**

- Ajax, if I can render the view in another URL.
- HTML '< Form >', if I can pass the javascript array.
- Or C# Helper, maybe passing the javascript array to a view model, but I don't know how to.
- PartialView? Not a solution.

Comment: You can't return a View when using Ajax. You need to return a Partial View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...that I want to send to a **ActionResult**.

I believe you may have a little confusion here. In ASP.NET MVC, anything that *receives a request*, either from AJAX or a full request, is an **action**. The result of that action, like a JSON response or a full page result, is an ActionResult.

Always think about it like **request > response**. Request is handled by your action, response is what the action outputs.

Now, to your question. Consider this page as the first one, that outputs the IDs from the DB:

```
<form method="post" action="/home/someaction">
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="arrayId" value="1" />1</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="arrayId" value="2" />2</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="arrayId" value="3" />3</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="arrayId" value="4" />4</label></li>
    </ul>
    <button>Post array to action SomeAction</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('form').on('submit', function () {
                $('checkbox:checked').each(function (ix, el) {
                    $(el).attr('name', 'arrayId[' + ix + ']');
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Let's see what's going on here:

- We have one checkbox for each item returned from the DB. Notice the **name** attr, it's important
- Everything's inside a form that points to our second action. This is the one that will receive the array
- When the form is submitted, we iterate through each selected checkbox to change the name to something like `arrayId[0]`. This is required. ASP.NET uses the name attr to bind the received data to what the action expects. If it's a collection (like a list or an array), the name must also include a 0-based indexer. That's what we're doing before posting the form.

The action that will receive this post looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string[] arrayId)
{
    return View(arrayId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To send data to the server via ajax is a good idea, but the problem is how to respond this to the user. One solution is to redirect user to another page or to refresh the current page with appropriate changes. In this way you can use JavascriptResult.

```
return JavaScript("window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/...'");
```

or

```
return JavaScript("location.reload(true)");
```